# Warning INCHI with RDkit

Tags: python, rdkit

I am reading in molfiles. However, I sometimes get warnings like "Omitted undefined stereo".
I thought that the molecules that sanitized if I am using "MolFromMolFile".
What am I missing?

```
INCHI = Chem.MolToInchi(
        Chem.MolFromMolFile("xyz.mol"))
```

Answer (score 2):

This bug was resolved in Jun 2014 with this PR: [PR-226](https://github.com/ReactionMechanismGenerator/RMG-Py/pull/226)
You can pass `options='-SNon'` to silence those warnings like this:

```
mol = Chem.MolFromMolFile("xyz.mol")
Chem.inchi.MolToInchi(mol, options='-SNon')
```